# Question with specific answer closed as opinion based

Tags: discussion

[Why do arrays in .Net have Length but other collection types have Count?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/294603/why-do-arrays-in-net-have-length-but-other-collection-types-have-count?rq=1)

This top rated answer for this question explains clearly, and *specifically* why this is the case.

I do not believe this question prompts overly broad or opinionated answers...

Comment: cross-site duplicate: [Is asking “why” on language specifications still considered as “primarily opinion-based” if it can have official answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323382/839601) (an answer by Eric Lippert seems to be as authoritative as it gets)